# OpenCV&Python - Set specific colour to region of image

Tags: python, opencv

I am working with OpenCV and Python. I am detecting the face in a face image, I am focusing at the region of the face in the image and I create a mask (of zeros) which I want to fill in with white colour (or any colour in general) at the region of the face. My source code is the following:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('ManWithGlasses.jpg')

RGB_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

# Detect the face in the image
haar_face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
faces = haar_face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_img, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=8);

mask_face = np.zeros(RGB_img.shape[:2], np.uint8)


# Loop in all detected faces - in our case it is only one
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(RGB_img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0), 2)
        plt.imshow(RGB_img)
        plt.show()

        roi_rgb = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        mask_face[y:y + h, x:x + w] = [255, 255, 255]
```

However I get the following error:

```
  mask_face[y:y + h, x:x + w] = [255, 255, 255]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (462,462)
```

How can I set this region of the image to whichever colour I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
mask_face = cv2.rectangle(mask_face, (x,y), (x + w,y + h), (255,255,255), -1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I had this in my mind (but be aware that it is 'cv2' instead of 'cv' and '-1' instead of '1').

Answer (score 1):

The slicing method work's fine, but you need to create a `valid image`, `mask_face` need to be a `rgb image`:

```
mask_face = np.zeros(RGB_img.shape[:2] + (3,), np.uint8)
```

Then you can use slicing method or just draw a rectangle like [Maxime Guinin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48061708/5770721)

UPDATE to improve answer.

RGB images are multidimensional arrays with 3 dimensions (height, width and color channels), so, when you created `mask_face` you missed color channels, then `+ (3,)` to add this. This is like blank `rgb_image` is created, the first arg can be a `list` or a `tuple`:

```
blank_image = np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If you have some time to spare please elaborate a bit on your answer because it is not so obvious why for example you are doing '+ [3]' even though I got it now.

Comment: Yes, thanks for this. However I get the following error now: `mask_face = np.zeros(RGB_img.shape[:2] + [3], np.uint8)
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple`. Why is this?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, `RGB_img.shape[:2]` returns a tuple, so, you need `+ (3,)`, instead `+ [3]`, answer fixed.